# Create Guacamole users

Tags: java, api, guacamole

I have just set up [Guacamole](https://guacamole.apache.org/) 0.9.9 with a MySQL user database and [LDAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LDAP) authentication and it all works flawlessly so far.

However, I want to be able to create new users and connections in the MySQL database from outside of Guacamole. Is there a way to use the API to perform these tasks?

All I'm reading about the API is creating a new web application which embeds remote connections.

Comment: any progress on this? I am having a similar issue...

Comment: Unfortunately not. We switched to a full VPN since additional requirements couldn't be satisfied by guacamole.

Comment: Any solution in Guacamole 0.9.14? I have the same question.

Comment: Anyone has come alright with this? I have the same question. I'm trying to implement that in asp.net core 2.1. Please help us!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following MySQL commands in your code to create new users.

```
SET @salt = UNHEX(SHA2(UUID(), 256));
INSERT INTO guacamole_user (username, password_salt, password_hash, password_date) VALUES ('testuser', @salt, UNHEX(SHA2(CONCAT('testpass', HEX(@salt)), 256)), NOW());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create users with Guacamole REST API.

Firstly you need create a token:

**Endpoint:**

```
POST {{baseURL}}/api/tokens
```

**x-www-form-urlencoded:**

```
username: guacadmin
password: guacadmin
```

**Sample Response:**

```
{
    "authToken": "8144B9B1EBAF73E8EDCE08EF5C145F49C1C9F563F13E21BF7A1CEC43E74011A4",
    "username": "guacadmin",
    "dataSource": "postgresql",
    "availableDataSources": [
        "postgresql",
        "postgresql-shared"
    ]
}
```

After then you can create a user with using the token.

**Endpoint:**

```
POST {{baseURL}}/api/session/data/{{dataSource}}/users?token={{authToken}}
```

**Sample Request Body:**

```
{
    "username": "testuser",
    "password": "password",
    "attributes":{
        "disabled":"",
        "expired":"",
        "access-window-start":"",
        "access-window-end":"",
        "valid-from":"",
        "valid-until":"",
        "timezone": ""
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not that into REST API and since our server is behind VPN I am stricted to Client based REST API TOOLs. I use httpie in WSL2 Ubuntu and was able to create a Token but have no Idea how second part has to be done. We are running guacamole 1.3